# Is there anyway to know if my windows 7 was shutdown by the normal Menu or the shutdown command?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cmd.exe, shutdown, timer

Is there anyway to know if in some specific day a Windows 7 computer was shutdown using the normal "Windows button > Click Shutdown" or using the shutdown /s /t (seconds) from the command line?

Comment: I am afraid there is no such method. Even if I compare the logs of the two shutdown methods multiple times, I just see that their reason codes are different. But the reason code represents a lot of reasons for shutting down. So we can't use that to determine which way the computer is turned off.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I don't see how. These are just UI differences. They both call the same API.